# can you add intent triggers to child dialog in bot composer

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, bot-framework-composer

In Microsoft Bot Composer, can intents be added to child dialogs, or only to main dialog?

I see an option to add intents in child dialogs, but when I test (LUIS or regex) they do not get recognized.  However when I add them to main dialog they do.

Does this mean that all intents have to be loaded to main dialog only?  Then what is the point of `intent recognized` trigger?

Sample Case:

I created 2 intents.  `test2` and `custom`.  I put `test2` in main dialog.  And for `custom` I tested exact same intent (with same phrases) in main vs child dialog.

In first case, I got correct recognition.  In the other it either goes to wrong intent (test2) or gives 'not understood' response.

**UPDATE:**
Based on answers and further testing, it appears that intents to child dialog can only be recognized IF THE DIALOG IS ALREADY OPEN.  I.e., the intents are invisible at the start of conversation, and only visible if something opens the child dialog, and if the dialog continues to be open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you can add intent for child dialog also.
In Child dialog you have to set "Auto end dialog" property as false ( default is true) until end dialog is called , all intent(child dialog Intent) handle by the child dialog.

[image]

Comment: no, it did not work...  I changed the 'Auto end dialog' to false and  tried multiple intent and intent groups, and nothing gets picked up if the training is in child dialog

Comment: can you check the image ? I added test2 same intent in both main & child is working

Comment: is it possible you could share the zip of this bot?  So i could copy the implementation?  I can see on the image that it's working, but I can't get it to work locally

Comment: here find the sample  https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/BotTutorialSample/tree/master/BotComposer/DeleteChildDialog/ChildDialog/ChildDialog

Comment: When I try to open the project with composer (v2.1.1), it says that it was created in an older version, and when it tries to convert, there are errors.  It could be also that examples are based off qna?  which i don't have, so I'm not getting anything...  But if i understand it correct based on the image, you were able to start intents in child dialog only because you opened it first, right?  Which i think means that unless the dialogs are forced open, the intents won't be checked, right?

Comment: Doesn't that mean that all dialogs would have to be forced opened at bot launch for intents inside the child dialogs to be scanned?

Comment: yes , dialog must be open ( bot will process always active dialog )

Comment: Sorry for the comment on a very old post. Is it still the same. Am I supposed to open all my dialogs in the parent dialog. On web chat, we have the conversationUpdate activity where we can do this. What about Teams bots where we dont get this ? User will have to type something specific to invoke all the dialogs right ? Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1. Go to the setting of your "Begin a new dialog" activity that triggers the child dialog, set "Activity processed" to **false**.
2. In the child dialog, delete the "BeginDialog" trigger that was created by default.

This will forward original user input to the child dialog and its Luis without asking the user again. No need to set false "Auto end dialog" as in the other answer.

Comment: What should happen if I want something should be handle in BeginDialog(child dialog) or I want invoke the same dialog in another use case ( Not invoke by Luis)